# Spring Boot -- Can't use LocalDateTime with GraphQL filter library

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, graphql

Long story short, I have a custom filter object that I use to convert into JPA queries.

```
// env is a DataFetchingEnvironment
FilterExpression filterExpression = builder.args(env.getArguments()).build();
Specification<BaseModel> specification = filterExpression.getExpression(ExpressionFormat.JPA);
```

The stack trace is from JPA, but it's because the filter library is converting the date into a strange format

```
Parameter value [Wed Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC 2023] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Wed Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC 2023] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
```

It seems like the filter expression coerces the argument to a `Date` type but the SQL column is a `DateTime`.

When I look online there are some solutions to this using native queries which would NOT work here because of the custom filter object I'm using (I can query on multiple fields by building a JPA expression, and the only filter that isn't working is `LocalDateTime`).

Edit: More detail

In SQL the column type is `DateTime` and there's nothing special specified for the column definition on hibernate.

Full stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Wed Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC 2023] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDateTime (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:774) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy207.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:801) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:779) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:517) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Edit2:

The problem is with how my graphql library is building the datetime filter from `FilterExpression.newFilterExpressionBuilder().args(env.getArguments()).build()`. I was able to somewhat bypass things by omitting the DateTime filter and adding the specification myself afterwards but ideally I could get things to work with the filter expression builder.

Comment: `UTC` -- Why does the parameter have a time offset (Universal Time Clock in this case)? LocalDateTime cannot accept time offsets or time zones. It seems the parameter value you are passing is a timestamp **WITH TIME ZONE** or similar. Get rid of the time zone.

Comment: Looks like a toString was called on a java.util.Date object, which prints off the date in the default local/timezone/format. It doesn't mean there is a UTC timezone specified, only that the value represents midnight Jan 18th in UTC. This is a java exception, so the problem is with what you are passing in to the query - your parameter isn't a LocalDateTime, so check your method signatures and values, as you may need to convert it, as I don't think this is specifications changing anything to a Date object. How and where are you getting this exception from exactly? (ie show the stack trace)

Comment: I'm passing the value through a graphql playground, and it only accepts certain inputs or it hangs indefinitely

Comment: The input I pass in is `2023-01-18T00:00` and it appears to parse to a LocalDateTime correctly. I'll add the full stack trace to the post

Comment: When I translate to a LocalDateTime, I can also use a dateFormatter but that doesn't really change anything because I'm always able to translate to a LocalDateTime object. The issue comes when trying to execute in JPA

Comment: Maybe you could create+share a test case which recreates the problem? Or some more of your code allowing others to recreate the problem? This would allow potential fixes to be checked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being this part of the filter library. I had to fork the repo, remove the block of code, and then publish my own version of the library: https://github.com/intuit/graphql-filter-java/issues/29

Hopefully it can be fixed more formally for others in the future :)